# When i try to build i get this error , what can i do

Tags: android

Is there a solution to this problem :

```
>     * Exception is:
>     org.gradle.api.CircularReferenceException: Circular dependency between the following tasks:
>     :app:processDebugResources
>     \--- :app:processDebugResources (*)
```

Comment: Could you provide us the build.gradle? (Module: app)

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation project(path: ':app')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}

Comment: Add your comment to the question.